# Making PhpStorm recognise instances defined in PHPUnit setUp

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

Consider the following test case:

```
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public $foo;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->foo = new Foo();
    }

    public function testBar()
    {
        $expected = 42;
        $actual = $this->foo->bar();

        $this->assertEqual($expected, $actual);
    }
```

Because `$this->foo` is instantiated in `setUp` PhpStorm doesn't recognize it as an instance of `Foo` in the subsequent test methods. As a result a lot of the IDE power is lost (loosing completion lookups and such). PhpStorm even complains that `bar` isn't a method of `$this->foo` even though it is.

Is there an effective way of getting PhpStorm to recognize instances defined in `setUp`; much like it would if they were defined in `__construct`? Maybe there's a whole suite of PhpStorm functionality I'm missing? Or just a hacky work around?

Comment: Just use standard PHPDoc `/** @var Foo */` before your `public $foo;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPStorm read the standard PHPDOC, as example you can define as:

```
class CustomerHelperTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

    /**
     * @var \Acme\DemoBundle\Service\CustomerHelper
     */
    protected $customerHelper;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->customerHelper = new CustomerHelper(
        );
    }
```